# Determine application's name which my PDF has been opened in?

Tags: javascript, pdf-form

I am developing a PDF form and I would like to warn users that this form has been only tested in certain application say *Adobe Acrobat Reader* for instance. 
Is there any way that I could leverage JavaScript to determine the name of the application which user has opened my PDF in? i.e. if user opened the PDF in *Bluebeam*, a message box to be displayed saying blah blah blah.

Comment: No, and I think this would be quite a security issue if you could determine what someone is reading your file with?

Comment: Hmm. How about determining whether client's PDF handler is fully supporting XFA or not?